# Why amcl is not working?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to implement amcl on rviz using nxt and kinect.

However, it just can't localize itself. I have used rviz 2D pose estimate to select the initial location of the robot as shown below (but no particle cloud is shown after I release my mouse click button -> rviz highlighted the particle cloud in yellow)

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/amcl_2D_pose_estimate_not_working-1.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/amcl_2D_pose_estimate_not_working-1.png)

The navigation stack is working perfectly, it can plan the required navigation path and move to the desired destination, as shown in the pictures below:

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/navigationpath.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/navigationpath.png)

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/navigationtodestination.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/navigationtodestination.png)

The rxgraph is shown below (amcl did received all the 4 needed subscribed topics which are /scan, /tf, /map and /initialpose [reference](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl)) :

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/amcl_rxgraph_map_topic_connected_but_cannot_localize.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/amcl_rxgraph_map_topic_connected_but_cannot_localize.png)

[Clearer Image for rxgraph](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/74451611/amcl_rxgraph_map_topic_connected_but_cannot_localize.png)

The tf_frames is shown below (I can't detect any error with the tf_frames as well ,hmm...):

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/tfview_framesResult.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/April2012/tfview_framesResult.png)

The yaml files:

**costmap_common_params.yaml:**

```
obstacle_range: 2.5

raytrace_range: 3.0

footprint: [[0.305, 0.278], [0.04, 0.193], [-0.04, 0.193], [-0.282, 0.178], [-0.282, -0.178], [-0.04, -0.193], [0.04, -0.193], [0.305, -0.278]]

inflation_radius: 0.55

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: openni_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: false, clearing: true}
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml:**

```
  global_costmap:

  global_frame: /map
  
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  
  update_frequency: 5.0
  
  static_map: true
```

**local_costmap_params.yaml:**

```
  local_costmap:
  
  global_frame: odom_combined
  
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  
  update_frequency: 5.0
  
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  
  static_map: false
  
  rolling_window: true
  
  width: 6.0
  
  height: 6.0
  
  resolution: 0.05
```

**base_local_planner_params.yaml:**

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 0.45

  min_vel_x: 0.1

  max_rotational_vel: 1.0

  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

  acc_lim_th: 3.2

  acc_lim_x: 2.5

  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: False
```

***The launch files:***

**amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch:**

```
<launch>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">

  <param name="use_map_topic " value="true"/>

  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->

  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>

  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />

  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>

  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>

  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>

  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>

  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>

  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>

  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>

  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>

  <!-- translation std dev, m -->

  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>

  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>

  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>

  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>

  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>

  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>

  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>

  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>

  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->

  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>

  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>

  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>

  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>

  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>

  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
  
</node>

</launch>
```

**move_base.launch:**

```
<launch>

  <master auto="start"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->

  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find not_good)/Maps/map.pgm 0.05"/>
 
  <!-- tf /map to /odom_combined -->

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom_combined" args="100 100 0 0 0 0 /map /odom_combined 100"/>

  <!--- Run AMCL -->

  <include file="$(find not_good)/amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch" />

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

  <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />

  <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

  <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

  <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

  <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

</node>

</launch>
```

***************Question :Why AMCL is still not working at all? Hmm...************

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32199/why-amcl-is-not-working?/) by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your odometry frame is `odom_combined`, you should change the `odom_frame_id` AMCL parameter to `odom_combined`. I see you have it set to `odom`.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on 2012-04-23**:
Thanks Eric Perko. =)

**Comment by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on 2012-05-04**:
Thanks Eric Perko =) Could you please have a look at this post as well thanks http://answers.ros.org/question/33319/rosrun-vs-roslaunch

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Transforms)

AMCL provides the transform from /map to /odom_combined so you do not need the static_transform_publisher node running

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2